# How to make a FLV video appear always on top

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

first I thank those for any help for this question! =)

What I am trying to do is make a button so when you hover over it a FLV video plays.  I am able to make it play successfully. the problem is it is not always on top of everything.  Some of the other buttons are still on top while the video plays which is blockin the video.  So my general questions is there a way to make a movie clip "Always on Top" so no other elments can block it while it is showing.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your button is in the same flash swf as your movie will be playing in...

If so, are the movie and the button in the same layer? Can you put the movie in a different layer, above all the buttons?

(Simple how-to on layers: http://www.entheosweb.com/Flash/layers.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the response Stobor =)  its a probelm where it doesnt matter the position of the layer.  There are multiple buttons, so for example you hove over a button and the video is fine on top of the buttons. But then you hover over the other buttons and the video shows but the previous button is on top.  Is there any general command to always allow something to have to priority and be in top? Thank you soo much!

Comment: @Darren: Okay, I'll look into this some more... Just to clarify: are the video and buttons on the same layer, or different layers?

Comment: Thank you soo much Stober!  I have placed a sample of the flash movie im working on to better illustrate the problem. Here is the link http://www.magicxstudios.com/pisp/testvid.html  THe buttons are on all the same layer. Even though on the same layer though you know of course that flash still orders the buttons.  If there was just an easy way so that flash code or method that would let the popup of the video be in front of all objects regardless of what is behind. Once again thank you soo much!

-Darren

Comment: Not to harp on the same point too much, but which layer are the video popups in? Are they in the same layer with the three buttons, or in a different layer?

Comment: Yes they are on the same layer as the buttons. For each button the video rests on the over frame. So when the mouse hovers over it the video pops up.  Should I be making the videos popup instead on a different layeR? Thanks a milllion!

Comment: Yeah - that was my original suggestion... Create a new layer above all the buttons, make the video pop up in that layer.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that lol?  How could i make the button so that when it hovers over a button it shows the video if its on a total separate layer? thanks